# How to extract file .xlsx out of the tmp folder in lambda

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, email, lambda, aws-lambda

I have a zip file that upon unlocking opens up a .xlsx file. When I use the Zipfile extract function in my lambda function, It stores it in a directory called 'tmp'. Below is the code I have written.

```
def extract_zip(input_zip):
    input_zip=ZipFile(input_zip)
    with input_zip as zf:
        return zf.extractall(path='/tmp/',pwd=b'password')
```

My question is how can I access the .xlsx file in the 'tmp' directory? Essentially all I want to do is convert it into a data frame

```
df = pd.read_excel('tmp')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply read the file using Pandas as you would normally do:

```
df = pd.read_excel('/tmp/filename.xlsx')
```